# Error while using the Group By Clause

Tags: sql, group-by

I am getting the sql server error "the text ntext and image data types cannot be compared or sorted except when using is null or like" while executing

```
SELECT r.Shift, l.lab_title AS [Assigned Lab], u.user_name AS [L/A],
       CONVERT(varchar(100), t.Time) + '  To ' + CONVERT(varchar(100), h.Time) AS Timing
  FROM table_roaster_time_table AS r
       INNER JOIN table_time AS t ON r.timeId = t.timeId AND r.timeId = t.timeId
       INNER JOIN table_user AS u ON r.user_id = u.user_id
       INNER JOIN table_labs AS l ON r.lab_id = l.lab_id
       INNER JOIN table_time2 AS h ON r.timeId2 = h.timeId2
 GROUP BY r.Shift, l.lab_title, u.user_name
```

Don't know what's the problem. I have used aggregate function also with it, just for formality but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your `r.Shift` column is a `text` or `ntext` type.  Because of this it cannot be used in a `group by`

One option might be to use a CAST on the suspect column, but you might loose data.  Example:

```
SELECT        r.Shift, l.lab_title AS [Assigned Lab], u.user_name AS [L/A], CONVERT(varchar(100),     t.Time) + '  To ' + CONVERT(varchar(100), h.Time) AS Timing
FROM            table_roaster_time_table AS r INNER JOIN
                     table_time AS t ON r.timeId = t.timeId AND r.timeId = t.timeId INNER JOIN
                     table_user AS u ON r.user_id = u.user_id INNER JOIN
                     table_labs AS l ON r.lab_id = l.lab_id INNER JOIN
                     table_time2 AS h ON r.timeId2 = h.timeId2
GROUP BY CAST(r.Shift as varchar(max), l.lab_title, u.user_name
```

You could also look at querying the data without the `text` column and then doing a second query to get the missing column.  Example:

```
with temp as
(
    SELECT        l.lab_title AS [Assigned Lab], u.user_name AS [L/A], CONVERT(varchar(100),     t.Time) + '  To ' + CONVERT(varchar(100), h.Time) AS Timing
    FROM            table_roaster_time_table AS r INNER JOIN
                         table_time AS t ON r.timeId = t.timeId AND r.timeId = t.timeId INNER JOIN
                         table_user AS u ON r.user_id = u.user_id INNER JOIN
                         table_labs AS l ON r.lab_id = l.lab_id INNER JOIN
                         table_time2 AS h ON r.timeId2 = h.timeId2
    GROUP BY l.lab_title, u.user_name
)
SELECT   r.Shift, t.lab_title AS [Assigned Lab], t.user_name AS [L/A] --etc
 FROM            table_roaster_time_table AS r 
 INNER JOIN temp as t
on  r.id = t.id --or whatver
```

Also, this SQL seems unnecessary:

```
r.timeId = t.timeId AND r.timeId = t.timeId
```

Comment: Should I change my all columns which are used in it and is having Text as a data type?

Comment: More clearly stated assuming variables ending in id are ints one of the columns in the GROUP BY clause is of one of the types you can't compare.

Comment: I'm not sure I would change it if you need it.  Some options might be to cast it as varchar(max) or possible to do two seperate queries, the first grouping and not including the `ntext` column and the second joining on the original query to get the ntext column...

Comment: @AbeMiessler your first query is giving error incorrect syntax near ',' and second query is giving error: "Column table_time.Time is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause; what should I do now?

Comment: You will need to debug it.  I'm giving you a place to start that is 99% of the way there, but you will need to take it the rest of the way.  Both of these error messages explain what the problem is.